# Setting up react using gulp and babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, require, babeljs

Good day everyone.

For a couple days I've been having a headache trying to setup react.  So far I have the following.

Folder Structure>

```
gulpfile.js
content
|--js
|--src
   |--libraries
   |  |--jquery (and others)
   |--react
      |--containers
      |  |--my-base-file.jsx
      |--components
         |--my-first-component.jsx
         |--my-second-component.jsx
```

Now, my react pieces look like this:

my-base-file.jsx

```
var FirstComponent = require('FirstComponent');
ReactDOM.render(<FirstComponent />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

my-first-component.jsx

```
var SecondComponent = require('SecondComponent');

class FirstComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Some Content</p>
                <SecondComponent />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = FirstComponent;
```

my-second-component.jsx

```
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                **MAGIC**
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = SecondComponent;
```

Now my gulpfile.js looks something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var react = require('gulp-react');

var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var folders = {
    jsOut: "./content/js/",
    common: [
        "./content/src/libraries/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js",
        "**MORE-FILES**",
    ],
    example: [
        "./content/src/react/containers/my-base-file.jsx"
    ],
};

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src(folders.common.concat(folders.example))
        .pipe(babel({
            plugins: ['transform-react-jsx']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('example.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.jsOut));
});
```

I know is not necessarily pretty, but I've been changing this quite a bit for the last 48 hours :P

Now, at the end, it seems to be combining files properly. I get an 'example.js' file with the pieces from common and the base file. now the problem is that I can't make it pull the pieces using require.

If I don't use require I can just compile everything and it combines it properly. But I would like to be able to tell which dependencies each file has, while still being able to use jsx files.

I tried using react directly by just removing ".pipe(babel(.....)" with ".pipe(react())" and just specifying all the files at once.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but all the tutorials I see have different approaches, and I feel by implementing one of the tutorials I remove what I learned from the others.

Any help will be appreciated.  I'm kinda new to this way of developing JS, especially setting it up with gulp.

Thank you.

Comment: you need a module bundler if you want to `require` modules: webpack, rollup, parcel

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but... jQuery in a react app? That's masochism :)

Comment: @FabioLolli or legacy? ;)

Comment: @FabioLolli  bootstrap was a requirement, and it has jQuery as a dependency apparently :(

Comment: One thing about the folder structure - when you install dependencies with npm, they go into root/node_modules - in your structure I can see jQuery under root/src/libraries... I don't want to say it's wrong, because there are use cases for that, but you should also consider that most of your npm dependencies will go into node_modules. You should keep that in mind while setting up your build process...

Comment: Other thing, you're saying you're new with Gulp and this way of JS, so my question is: do you really want to go down the Gulp rabbit hole? It does give you a lot of control, and if this is for training purposes it's helpful, as long as you're planning to use Gulp. But if your goal is to get an app out, or training for the future, I'd switch to something automatic, like webpack or other bundlers. What I personally did to get it going, is create an app using https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app then ejected it to get control of the configs, and I manually went through the default configs

Comment: ...went through the default configs and made sure I understood what they were doing, and whether I needed them or not. I too started with Gulp, but I feel like npm scripts and webpacks outclass it 100%.If you're coming from a similar background as I am, I'd suggest you at least think about going from gulp to npm scripts, just because it's becoming the standardized way for running tasks in the node/js environment.

Comment: Thank you guys!  I added webpack for the js pieces and realized I wasn't exporting my modules properly.  In the end I had gulp taking care of common js library bundles and scss, and used webpack to compile the app specific pieces.  Now I just need to understand how to use redux :D  You guys were really helpful.